# How to notate derivative at a certain point?

Tags: derivatives

I have a simple question.

I have so far always used $f'(x)$ as a derivative notation.
For example, if I have a function $y=x^4$ then $y'(x)=4x^3$ and $y'(x)=0$ when $x_1=x_2=x_3=2$. And If I want to find whether $x=0$ is a minima or maxima point then I have done like this: $y''(x)=12x^2$ and $y''(2)=12*2^2=48>0$ so it's the minima point.

Now I have started using $dy/dx$ and everything is fine:

$dy/dx=4x^3$

$dy/dx=0$

$x_1=x_2=x_3=2$

$d^2y/dx^2=12x^2$

But now I'm a bit confused because I don't know how should I note the second derivative at $x=2$ with $dy/dx$. Is it correct to write it like this $dy/d(2)$?

I know that the question might seem a bit dumb but I just would like to know what is the correct notation?

Comment: the value of the derivative of $y$ at a point $x = a$ can be written as
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\left.{\!\!\frac{}{}}\right|_{x=a} = \frac{dy}{dx}(a)$$
Take a look at
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation

Comment: @Ömer Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: there is no minima at $x_1=x_2=x_3=2$

Comment: @LincolnHawk Yes, of course. I made the error by accident. The minima is at $x = 0$. Thanks!